# Do minors need ID to fly in the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa, minors, domestic-travel

Are **minors** (under 18) required to have photo identification when traveling in the U.S?

Comment: @Flimzy he did tag it [tag:air-travel] :) I'll update the title tho.

Comment: @MarkMayo: That might include catipulting.... :P

Answer (score 5):

[The TSA's page on Identification for flights states](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids):

> Adult passengers (18 and over) are required to show a U.S. federal or
>   state-issued photo ID in order to be allowed to go through the
>   checkpoint and onto their flight.

So that would imply that minors don't have to have ID.

However, to further confirm this, I'll quote from an airline - [JetBlue's page](http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webisapi.dll?New,Kb=askBlue,case=obj%282106%29):

For children:

> Children
>
> Children under the age of 18 and traveling on a domestic flight do not
>   need to show identification or documentation unless they are under 14
>   days old (physician’s letter required) or are traveling as a lap child
>   (proof of age may be required).

and since you didn't specify if they were travelling with an adult:

> Unaccompanied Minors
>
> Unaccompanied minors must check in at the ticket counter. An
>   unaccompanied minor does not need photo ID. However, the adult
>   dropping them off and picking them up will need photo ID. This adult
>   must be named in the reservation.